# AsyncTask toString() method does not work

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-asynctask, tostring, amazon-simpledb

I am trying to create a domain in AWS-SimpleDB inside an AsyncTask class, but the App crashes every time I execute it. The code snippet for the case where it works and it crashes are below:

This works:

```
   protected Void doInBackground(Param... params) {
            private static final String APP_DOMAIN = "Domain1";

            AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constants.SECRET_KEY);
            this.sdbClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(credentials);
            CreateDomainRequest cdr = new CreateDomainRequest(APP_DOMAIN);
            this.sdbClient.createDomain(cdr);
}
```

But, when I wanted to add the Date String to the Domain name, the app crashes:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Param... params) {
        static Date dt = new Date();
        private static final String APP_DOMAIN = "Domain1"+dt.toString();

        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constants.SECRET_KEY);
        this.sdbClient = new AmazonSimpleDBClient(credentials);
        CreateDomainRequest cdr = new CreateDomainRequest(APP_DOMAIN);
        this.sdbClient.createDomain(cdr);
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it that AsyncTask cannot have a Date object passed to it?

Comment: Post the stacktrace and we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you are sending "domain1Fri Feb 20 22:50:07 EET 2015" as a domain name, there can't be whitespaces.

Comment: I tried the following to avoid white spaces, but it also crashed the app:           Date dt1 = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat ft1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM"); CreateDomainRequest cdr = new CreateDomainRequest(APP_DOMAIN+ft1.format(dt1));'

Comment: From the doc for CreateDomainRequest you can have a-z, A-Z, 0-9, '_', '-', and '.' in the domain name.

Comment: Thank you so much. That was the fix :)